# Does the Infestor's slime trail ever serve a useful purpose?

Tags: starcraft-2

The Infestor leaves a short trail of slime everywhere it goes. Is there any purpose to this trail? Has anyone ever used it to their advantage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid not, the infestor's awesomely gross slime trail is sadly, purely aesthetic.

Answer (score 3):

I think this trail of slime is rather disadvantage for the zerg player.

Because the slime trail of the Infestor lasts several seconds after the Infestor passes by, if your opponent sees it it can tell him/her both:

1. You have Infestors.
2. Gives an idea of where they're going.

Comment: At least they can march in single file to hide their numbers.